# Can I implement a method from a trait using a case statement?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I am trying to implement a method using a case statement, but the following code does not compile.

I am aware I can get this working by using a pattern match, but am curious as to why the case statement is incompatible as a direct implementation....

```
trait Calculation[Input, Result] {
   def calculate(in: Input): Result
}

class CalculationImpl : Calculation[String, int] {
   // missing parameter type for expanded function
   // The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
   def calculate = {
      case "one" => 1
      case "two" => 2
      case s: String => 0
   }
}
```

As a compromise, I could change the semantics of the trait so that `calculate` becomes a  parameterless method which returns a `Function1`, rather than a method which takes an `Input` parameter and returns a `Result`. However, this is not ideal...

```
trait Calculation[Input, Result] {
   def calculate: Input => Result // Works, but semantics have changed.
}

class CalculationImpl : Calculation[String, int] {
   def calculate = {
      case "one" => 1
      case "two" => 2
      case s: String => 0
   }
}
```

(note: the above is pseudo-code - I have not tried compiling this exact code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to fix your syntax and it will work:

```
def calculate(s: String) = s match {
  case "one" => 1
  case "two" => 2
  case s: String => 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get closer to the original semantics and still cut the boilerplate by defining `calculate` as a function value:

```
trait Calculation[Input, Result] {
   type F = Input => Result
   val calculate: F
}

class CalculationImpl extends Calculation[String, Int] {
   val calculate: F = {
      case "one" => 1
      case "two" => 2
      case s: String => 0
   }
}
```

Comment: 'As a compromise, I could change the semantics of the trait so that calculate becomes a parameterless method which returns a Function1, rather than a method which takes an Input parameter and returns a Result. However, this is not ideal'

Comment: Yes, I saw that. However, this is a different proposal. Unlike defining `calculate` as a parameterless method (with the semantics that evaluating `calculate` might return a different function value each time), my approach defines `calculate` as a fixed function value. This is as close as you can get to the original semantics of a one-argument `calculate` method while still avoiding the extra boilerplate.